# Visual studio 2017 professional not showing option for windows driver project

Tags: windows, sdk, visual-studio-2017, driver, wdk

My windows version is Win 10 1803. I installed Visual studio professional 2017, and along with that I installed SDK 10.0.17134.1 and WDK 10.0.17134.1. I restarted the system, and the visual code, yet the option of creating a Windows driver project under Visual C++ is not showing.

Methods tried:
Re-installation of WDK,
Rebooting the system,
Using same version of WDK and SDK as mentioned in Microsoft site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/465b2453-4fdc-48f4-98d8-6b2996238f25/preview-wdk-10016257-does-not-install-with-vs-2017-release

Since the extension that works with Visual studio does not pop-up on its own, manually executing through cmd solves the purpose.